# Search for variations of a regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like `inuput_text = "this is an example test"`.
normally if I want to find `"example test"` in the `input_test` I do it like this:

```
if "example test" in inuput_text:
    print("we have a match")
```

Now what if I have other variety of `"example test"` like `"example_test"` or `"example-test"` and I want to match them with `input_text`?

I think that `regex` would be okay but I'm confused here.

**Edit:**

I think of regex to check if we have a white space and then genrate a list of strings replacing the white space with `_` or `-`, and after that I can search for these generated strings in the input text.

Comment: If your examples always follow this pattern, you could delete the 8th character and see if it matches "exampletest"

Comment: try reading here about [re the python regex package](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and you can also read [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: the problem is they don't, i can have all the words

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your search term to a regex, then match that.

```py
import re

pattern = re.escape(search_term).replace(r"\ ", "[ _-]")
match = re.search(pattern, input_text)
if match:
   ...
```

Comment: While I think this code *may* answer the question (in a clever way), it would be better to include more context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. That way it would be a lot more useful in the long run (to both the OP as well as other readers).

Comment: thankyou for yoyr answers, i solved the problem using your both suggestions, but i end up with another case like this how can i match `test` with `tést`  and `têst`

Comment: @mohanadalmowahid tack on another `.replace()` to the end of that second line- `.replace("e", "[eéê]")`

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
import re

input_text = "this is an example_test"
match = re.search("example[-_ ]test", input_text)

print(match.group())
```

You can use the regex `"example[-_ ]test"` to search for the text and you can use `match.group()` to get the matched string. You can define the characters between the example and test inside `[]`.

To know more, follow this link: [Python RegEx Match Object](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_regex_match.asp)

Comment: `[\W_]` will be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you can list out all the possible variations then you can search for all of them by creating a regex that does that. Here's what I mean:

```
import re


possibilities = "example test", "example_test", "example-test"
escaped = {re.escape(possibility) for possibility in possibilities}
pattern = '|'.join(escaped)
regex = re.compile(pattern)

test_strings = """\
Lorem ipsum dolor example test sit amet
Quisque semper, tellus quis pharetra viverra.
Fusce example_test molestie nisi enim
Curabitur convallis viverra example-test dolor vel tristique.
Ut nunc ante, fermentum example*test.
""".splitlines()

for input_text in test_strings:
    print(f'{input_text=!r}')
    match = regex.search(input_text)
    if match:
        print(f'    Matches: {match.group()!r}')
    else:
        print("    Doesn't match anything.")
```

Here's the results:

```
input_text='Lorem ipsum dolor example test sit amet'
    Matches: 'example test'
input_text='Quisque semper, tellus quis pharetra viverra.'
    Doesn't match anything.
input_text='Fusce example_test molestie nisi enim'
    Matches: 'example_test'
input_text='Curabitur convallis viverra example-test dolor vel tristique.'
    Matches: 'example-test'
input_text='Ut nunc ante, fermentum example*test.'
    Doesn't match anything.
```